# Couting Discord Bot's Guilds(In Python)?

Tags: python, bots, discord

Attempting to count how many servers/guilds my bot is in.
I've check a few forums before, and seems like for do it, I need to use the len().

I tried making it, by doing the follow command:

Guilds = len([s] for s in self.servers)

When doing it, I get the following error:
"TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()"

I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a comprehension that results in a generator.

You can probably fix it by doing len([s for s in self.servers]).

EDIT:

Generator is an object that does not hold elements in memory but you can still loop over them. Since it doesn't create a list from which to ask the length from you can't perform len().

Comment: Thanks it works.
Btw, I tried, set that as the bot's playing game, but somewhy it shows "playing " and not the guilds/servers.